# Restore Failed using C# Code

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, restore

My problem is that I can't restore my database in wpf using C# code. The error is 'Restore failed for Server 'DELL/LOCALSERVER'. I just found the code I'm using and it's this one:

//for getting .bak file path

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.ShowDialog();
  txtBackupPath.Text = ofd.FileName;
}

private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@server, userId, password);
  Server sqlServerInstance = new Server(con);
  Restore destination = new Restore();
  destination.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
  destination.Database = initial_catalog;
  BackupDeviceItem source = new BackupDeviceItem(txtBackupPath.Text, DeviceType.File);
  destination.Devices.Add(source);
  destination.ReplaceDatabase = true;
  destination.SqlRestore(sqlServerInstance);
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The restore of database " + "'H2RPDB'" + " completed sccessfully", "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  con.Disconnect();
}
```

I don't know what's wrong being new to this code. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: **WHERE** do you get this error, on what line of code?

Comment: I get this error from destination.SqlRestore(sqlServerInstance);

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that it is the server that is opening the file and thus the path to it has to be valid from the servers perspective? Ie `C:\test.bak` is on the servers C: disk.

Comment: So, I can't restore or even backup a database in other path like for example in Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the code is correct. It's just that the system doesn't have any permission to access the path I'm trying to access. Other than that, it works.